# Relative Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout of a user entry form.when i enter username and password and hit the submit button.the content should be saved and another div with three textboxes and editboxes should appear in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the content *might not* be the best solution.

Anyway, you can create all these elements together in the same layout and set the "div with three textboxes and editboxes" initially to "hidden".

After you have clicked the button and triggered the desired event, you grab the desired elements and make them visible while setting the unwanted elements to hidden again.

Charles Merriams answer would be the more elegant and cleaner way, this only answers the "base" question.

Answer (score 0):

The magic word you need to look at is "Intent".  You call your own application in order to switch layouts after the submit button.

You may find the Notepad tutorial useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try what `DrColossos` said or you can try by just setting a different contentview on button click.